# Logging history for Sharepoint 2010 Foundation

Tags: logging, auditing

Is there any way to get a record of who entered the portal with the date and time?

Answer (score 0):

If you have logging enabled in IIS, you can check the IIS logs.  You can also check the Content Viewing report in SharePoint if you had auditing enabled and configured during the period in question.

Comment: But the IIS Reports does not show me the username only the IP

Comment: In the IIS log format settings you need to make sure you include User Name (cs-username) as one of the logging fields.

Answer (score 0):

When you use IIS log analyzers make sure . You filter for the time window and that will do the job for you and display the no of users in the time frame.

Please write back in case you need some analysis to be done.